# use python to write to a specific column is a .csv file

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a .csv file where I need to overwrite a certain column with new values from a list.

Let's say I have the list L1 = ['La', 'Lb', 'Lc'] that I want to write in column no. 5 of the .csv file.

If I run:

```
L1 = ['La', 'Lb', 'Lc']
import csv
with open(r'C:\LIST.csv','wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for i in L1:
        w.writerow(i)
```

This will write the L1 values to the first and second column.

First column will be 'L', 'L', 'L' and second column 'a', 'b', 'c'

I could not find the syntax to write to a specific column each element from the list. (this is in Python 2.7). Thank you for your help!

(for this script I must use IronPython, and just the built in Libraries that comes with IronPython)

Comment: you can combine read and write. read each line from source file, apply a change to some column and write it to destination file, and at the end rename dest file to source file.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to do that, but I do not know how to write my list to a specific column in the .csv

Answer (score 0):

Although you could certainly use Python's built-in `csv` module to read the data, modify it, and write it out, I'd recommend the excellent [`tablib`](http://docs.python-tablib.org/) module:

```
from tablib import Dataset

csv = '''Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2
a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,f3,g3
'''

# Read a hard-coded string just for test purposes.
# In your code, you would use open('...', 'rt').read() to read from a file.
imported_data = Dataset().load(csv, format='csv')

L1 = ['La', 'Lb', 'Lc']

for i in range(len(L1)):
    # Each row is a tuple, and tuples don't support assignment.
    # Convert to a list first so we can modify it.
    row = list(imported_data[i])

    # Put our value in the 5th column (index 4).
    row[4] = L1[i]

    # Store the row back into the Dataset.
    imported_data[i] = row

# Export to CSV. (Of course, you could write this to a file instead.)
print imported_data.export('csv')

# Output:
# Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7
# a1,b1,c1,d1,La,f1,g1
# a2,b2,c2,d2,Lb,f2,g2
# a3,b3,c3,d3,Lc,f3,g3
```

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately this script must run on IronPython, so that is why I mention Python 2.7, as IronPython is similar to 2.7 (so no Pandas, etc.) . I can use only default libraries in IronPython.

Comment: Is `tablib` incompatible in some way with IronPython? Or why can you only use built-in libraries?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion/asking. The script will run on computers that I do not have access (I'm allowed) to install a specific library, or do any other customization. So I must use just what is installed by default w/ IronPython.  'tablib" is not in the Lib folder of IronPython.

Comment: Please edit your question with this constraint so others who try to answer will know that you can only use built-in libraries.